# How to denote $\underbrace{(1+n(1+n(1+\cdots)))}_{x-1 \text{times}}$ in a single expression?

Tags: notation

I learnt that,
$$
n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 +. . . + n^x = n\underbrace{(1+n(1+n(1+\cdots)))}_{x-1 \text{times}}
$$
So,I want to denote RHS in a single expression.

Comment: Ignore the [Horner form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method); simplify the LHS with  the [geometric sum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the left hand side by $(1 - n)$. This will collapse it down to $n - n^{x+1}$. Then divide by $(1 - n)$ to get a final answer of:

$$S = \frac{n - n^{x+1}}{1 - n}.$$

For more on [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 2):

You could say $$\text{Let }f(y) = n\cdot(1+ y)$$

and then the expression on the right becomes $$f^{x-1}(n).$$

Comment: Given you suppose that exponent denotes iteration, and not power ;)